# Sendmail or alternative?

Tags: php, linux, apache, email, sendmail

I have recently started a website that is built on Bootstrap, which uses a PHP mail function. It took me quite a while to figure out that I needed to install sendmail with Apache in order for it to send emails. However, sendmail is a big pain in the butt to configure properly, and I am not versed with any of PHP's mail abilities and requirements. I am attempting to use GoDaddy's SMTP servers to send emails from my domain, but the connections are failing and are coming from a generic domain with no TLD extension. This is a big issue as nearly all mail providers block generic domains, and documentation for setting up sendmail with SMTP servers is very sparse.

My questions are:

- Should I be using sendmail, or is there a better alternative to hook into GoDaddys SMTP servers
- A colleague at work told me that sendmail is actually an SMTP server itself, and is just relaying to GoDaddy, which may cause interference and authentication issues. Is this true?

If I am completely on the wrong path, links to good resources are much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: PHPMailer() is pretty good. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: +1 for PHPmailer. Also, if you want your mail to actually be *delivered* with some measure of reliability I would suggest not using your ISP's unauthenticated SMTP services.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the generic sendmail scripts provided by much of the providers, buy I would make sure I use my own SMTP authentication and that it comes from my own domain - no spam issues.

Comment: I am running my own apache server set up on a VPS. I am trying to set it up to come from my own domain, but no matter the sendmail configuration I have tired, it either fails to send, or comes from a generic domain.

Comment: do a search for sendmail.php scripts.  This page may help:  http://email.about.com/od/emailprogrammingtips/qt/PHP_Email_SMTP_Authentication.htm